# Php for each data to display in a comma seperated list with no space

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently i am displaying id's of users to display in a single line with a comma delimiter, the problem is it is having unwanted space between comma's

Showing like this
1, 6, 10

Should be like this
1,6,10

```html
  <div class="students">
<?php foreach ( $students as $student ) {
      
          $process = '';
          $result = 0;
          $student = learn_press_get_user( $student->ID );
          $data = $student->get_course_data($course->get_id());
          $status = $student->get_course_status($course->get_id());
          $result = $data->get_results();
   ?>

  <?php if ( $status ) {
  $process = ( $status == 'finished' ) ? 'finished' : 'in-progress';
  } ?>
  
       <?php echo $student->get_id(); ?>,
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution with `implode`

```
<div class="students">
  <?php 
  $student_ids = array();
  foreach ( $students as $student ) {
         $process = '';
         $result = 0;
         $student = learn_press_get_user( $student->ID );
         $data = $student->get_course_data($course->get_id());
         $status = $student->get_course_status($course->get_id());
         $result = $data->get_results();
         if ( $status ) {
           $process = ( $status == 'finished' ) ? 'finished' : 'in-progress';
         } 
         $student_ids[] =  $student->get_id(); // store all student id in array
    } 
    echo implode(',', $student_ids);
  ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="students">
    <?php 

        foreach ( $students as $student ) {
            $process = '';
            $result = 0;
            $student = learn_press_get_user( $student->ID );
            $data = $student->get_course_data($course->get_id());
            $status = $student->get_course_status($course->get_id());
            $result = $data->get_results();

            if ( $status ) {
            $process = ( $status == 'finished' ) ? 'finished' : 'in-progress';
            } 

            echo trim($student->get_id()) . ',';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @TalhaHameed now should work - check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Last php tag over closing div, has a space before it.

```
 <?php } ?>
```

Try writing loop within one php snippet.